# help with regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

could someone help me with the regex pattern that i could use to match the text "Cats" within the link element?

```
<A HREF="http://www.catingale2?subject=10023">Cats</A> forum
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$str = '<A HREF="http://www.catingale2?subject=10023">Cats</A> forum';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>#i', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Which gives :

```
string(4) "Cats"
```

And, as a sidenote : generally speaking, using regex to "parse" HTML is not quite a good idea !

Comment: what function could i use then to get the text within elements?

Comment: I you have a full portion of HTML *(something bigger than what you posted here, I mean)*, a "better" way, in many cases, would be to use an actual HTML parser ; like http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php and then go through the DOM, possibly using XPath queries.

Answer (score 2):

no need regex

```
$str=<<<EOF
<A HREF="http://www.catingale2?subject=10023">Cats</A> forum
<A HREF="http://www.catingale2?subject=10024">
 Dogs</A>
forum
EOF;
$s = explode("</A>",$str);
foreach($s as $v){
    if (strpos($v,"<A HREF")!==FALSE){
       $t=explode(">",$v);
       print end($t)."\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
# php test.php
Cats

 Dogs
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>
```

That's it. You could probably get away with:

```
<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>
```

or

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = '<A HREF="http://www.catingale2?subject=10023">Cats</A> forum';
if(preg_match('{<a.*?>(.*?)</a>}i',$input,$matches)) {
    $hyperlinked = $matches[1];
}
echo $hyperlinked; // print Cats
```

The regex used is: `<a.*?>(.*?)</a>`

Explanation:

```
<a.*?> - an opening anchor tag with any attribute.
(.*?)  - match and remember between opening anchor tag and closing anchor tag.
</a>   - closing anchor tag.
i      - to make the entire matching case insensitive
```